# stored procedure does not exist even though i have created

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i have created stored procedure as follows

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE gsx(IN location varchar(100),IN start timestamp,IN end timestamp)
As
   BEGIN
   SELECT count(CustomerFeed.overall) as sat  FROM ContactCenter LEFT JOIN CustomerFeed ON ContactCenter.callId = CustomerFeed.callId
WHERE date(ContactCenter.callClose) BETWEEN start AND end
AND ContactCenter.callStatus = 'Close'
AND CustomerFeed.overall IN ( 1, 2 )
AND ContactCenter.location=location
and ContactCenter.gNum!='';
   END 
DELIMITER ;
```

but wen execute by calling the procedure like

> call gsx('HO Bangalore','2013-07-01','2013-07-06')

i am getting procedure does not exist

> #1305 - PROCEDURE ampicare_crmdb.gsx does not exis but it was successfully executed

Comment: I can't see a any PHP here

Answer (score 1):

if you created the procedure exactly like written, you missed delimiter after END. Last 2 lines should be:

```
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: No, you have to end "CREATE PROCEDURE" with your set delimiter: //

Comment: even after putting END // same thing is repeating

Comment: How do you execute the create procedure? How do you tell it executed successfully?

Comment: after running the create procedure query i am getting message successfully executed.but while calling m getting PROCEDURE ampicare_crmdb.gsx does not exist

Comment: You didn't answer HOW you execute the query.

Comment: DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE gsx(IN location varchar(100),IN start timestamp,IN end timestamp)
As
   BEGIN
   SELECT count(CustomerFeed.overall) as sat  FROM ContactCenter LEFT JOIN CustomerFeed ON ContactCenter.callId = CustomerFeed.callId
WHERE date(ContactCenter.callClose) BETWEEN start AND end
AND ContactCenter.callStatus = 'Close'
AND CustomerFeed.overall IN ( 1, 2 )
AND ContactCenter.location=location
and ContactCenter.gNum!='';
   END //
DELIMITER ;